# How to create composite key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, code-first

I'm creating the mobile app with Azure Mobile Services like twitter.
To implement the "follow" function, I create the following model.

```
/*Model*/

//User Class
public class User : EntityData
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}

//Follow Class 

public class Follow : Entity Data
{      

        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Following")]
        public String FollowingId { get; set; }
        public virtual User Following { get; set; }

        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Followed")]
        public String FollowedId { get; set; }
        public virtual User Followed { get; set; }

}
```

Using the above code, Entity Framework creates a table.
User table is as expected, but Follow table is not.

Expected "Follow Table" has just two column as follows

```
FollowingId     FollowedId
```

`FollowingId` and `FollowedId` should be a composite key for `Follow table`
and Foreign Key for Id in User table.

If I set above, I cannot create the table using Entity framework.
Can anyone help me to create the table as expected?

Comment: Is there a primary key on FollowingId and FollowedId ? Are there referential constraints on FollowingId and FollowedId ? If so then EF is doing it correct.

Comment: Thx for the reply.
Primary key should be composite key, FollowingId and FollowedId which should be foreign key, too. However, following table were created,
That has, Id FollowingId FollowedId CreatedAt Version UpdateAt.

Comment: You need to define an attribute on username as well to make it key.